# Re-enable text-selection (Opera, webkit,ie)

Tags: javascript, jquery, textselection

How to re-enable the text-selection on IE, Opera & Webkit?

I disabled it like that:

```
$(this).mousedown(function(){return true;}); //Opera, webkit
$(this).bind('selectstart',function(){return true;}); //IE
```

(with firefox, I can easily re-enable it with `$(this).css('MozUserSelect','text')`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best thing to do would be to [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the event listeners.

Comment: It works, thanks!

$(this).unbind('mousedown');
$(this).unbind('selectstart');

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `bind()` and `unbind()` methods. Use `on()` and `off()` instead — preferred as of jQuery 1.7 and above.